# what does *they* refer to here? *measures* or *technological advances*? and does that sentence mean *they are needed to complement other factors*?

Tags: meaning-in-context, reference

**[SOURCE](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/9780821372555_ch02.pdf)**

Does *they* refer to  *measures* or *technological advances*? Does that sentence mean *they are needed to complement other factors*?

> The first WDR [1978 WDR] talked of **measures** to raise agricultural productivity
>   and observed that **technological advances**, now accelerated by biotechnologies and made more urgent by impending climate change, are a potent
>   force. **They** will need to complement other **factors**. 
>   The 1978 WDR briefly touched on **institutions**, which occupy far more space in the 2008 WDR. The 2008 report embraces the agricultural innovation system, mechanisms for promoting technology transfer, market coordination, and many other issues, including, of course, community-based development.
>
> ---

WDR=World Development Report

Answer (score 1):

As I read it *technological advances* drive the *measures*, so even though *they* refers to the *technological advances* (based on the rest of the paragraph and also due to proximity), the *technological advances* influence the *measures*.

So you can't say that *they* and *measures* are unrelated.